# Animation not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, animation, hover

Am ripping my hair out trying to implement a simple jquery animation that worked perfectly on another site I did. The only change I've made is in wanting to affect the animation to a different object than the selector (hoping I'm using these terms correctly). Oddly, even when I test to use the exact same scenario as the previous site, I get no results.

Can anyone see some obvious reason this isn't working?

This is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".themelist li").hover(
        function () {
            $(".themedescription").animate({opacity:"1"});
        },
        function () {
            $(".themedescription").animate({opacity:'0'}, "fast");
        }
    );  
});
```

This is my loop (wordpress):

```
echo "<div class='themelist'><ul>";
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo "<li>" . $term->name ."</li><div class='theme-description'>". $term->description. "</div>";
}
echo "</ul></div>";
```

This is my css:

```
.themelist {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}

.themelist li {width:200px;}

.theme-description {
text-align: left;
color: #CCC;
background: #333;
width:300px;
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
top:0;
left:200px;
opacity:0;
}
```

Ideas? Have searched all over and cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

***UPDATE***

Making progress, and now have a whole new problem. The following adjusted jquery finallyw works as far as making my animation run:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".themelist li").hover(function()
    {
$(".themedescription").filter(':not(:animated)').animate({opacity:"1"});
    },
(function()
    {
$(".themedescription").animate({opacity:"0"});
    }
)); 
});
```

But as you can imagine, instead of the div appearing one by one, each corresponding to the link in my list, they all appear at the same time. Gah. I should have seen this coming, but sort of assumed it would behave similar to a CSS display:none, and only show one at a time.

Is there another effect I can use that would fix this? Or do I need to generate individual classes so that my div .themedescription becomes .themedescription1, .themedescription2, etc?

Many thanks again. Your ideas are appreciated.
-jennyb

Answer (score 2):

`.themedescription` on jQuery code is typo error against html/wordpress code...

Please use `.theme-description` on your jQuery code.... with dash...